# How to create an ICO token that can be tradeable

Tags: contract-development, tokens, decentralized-exchange

How to create an ICO token with low fees that can be tradeable on decentralized exchanges.
E.g bob send 0.1ETH to the smart contract ,he receives the Eth for the ICO and can trade it, also the contract owner can withdraw the ETH or token sent to the smart contract

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy an ERC20 first, then you can create another contract example "Crowdsale" on this contract, you have to use "payable" modifier on your function, and depending on the amount of ETH sent to the contract you'll get the corresponding amount of tokens.

Comment: I am looking for the "crowdsale" and payable contract I can use sir